# Multiple HttpResponses in Django

Tags: python, django, httpresponse

I have a program that prints data in a step by step process.

Ex:

```
data = {'a', 'b'}
for op in data:
    if op == 'a':
        print 'Hello'
    elif op == 'b':
        print 'Bye'
```

This is the functional layout in the views.py class in my django project. Each print statement needs to output on the browser. I know for a single response I can use

```
return HttpResponse('Hello')
```

or just

```
return Response('Hello')
```

How do I achieve this for multiple outputs?

Comment: What do you mean by multiple output? What do you want to display in the webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Django docs for HttpResponse:

...if you want to add content incrementally, you can use response as a file-like object:

```
>>> response = HttpResponse()
>>> response.write("<p>Here's the text of the Web page.</p>")
>>> response.write("<p>Here's another paragraph.</p>")
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#passing-strings

Answer (score 0):

You would need to pass a list through the context, and then loop over the list in the template. For example:

views.py

```
def indexview(request):
    data = []
    for item in items_list:
        data.append(item)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'data': data}
```

index.html

```
{% for item in data %}
     {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the template system.  (See Hybrid's answer).

However, you can [pass an iterator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#passing-iterators), instead of a string to `HttpResponse`, and if necessary you can stream the results using, [`StreamingHttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse).

```
def someview(request):
    def mygen(data):  # generator
        for key, value in data.items():
            yield value

    data = {'a': 'Hello', 'b': 'Bye'}
    g = mygen(data)    
    return StreamingHttpResponse(g)
```